# Try catch ex.stack get first line only

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

How do I get the first line only of a console.log(ex.stack)>

For example I only want this:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'debug'
```

Out of this:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'debug'
    at eval at <anonymous> (unknown source)
    at eval (native)
    at Object._evaluateOn (unknown source)
    at Object._evaluateAndWrap (unknown source)
    at Object.evaluate (unknown source)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want the error message, just grab it directly. There's no need to parse it out from the full stack trace:

```js
var Object = {};
try {
  Object.debug();
} catch(ex) {
  console.log(ex.message);
}
```

If that's not possible for whatever the reason, the stack trace appears to be nothing but a string:

```
console.log(typeof ex.stack);
```

> string

... so pick your favourite string manipulation technique:

```
var Object = {};
try {
  Object.debug();
} catch(ex) {
  console.log(ex.stack.split("\n", 1).join(""));
}
```